# My Wordpress taxonomy should be required

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy and it works great, but i can't find a way to make it required in the dashboard.. Is there any way ?

This is the code of the taxonomy :

```
  function create_extra_cat_guidlines() {
       register_taxonomy(
      'cat',
      'pr_guidelines',
       array(
        'label' => __( 'Category' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'cat' ),
        'hierarchical' => true
      )
      );
  }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you seen [Require a Custom Taxonomy to be checked](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/19063/12615)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search with nog answers i decided to use a plugin:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/force-post-category-selection/installation/